# WebClient hangs until timeout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timeout, webclient

I try do download a web page using the WebClient, but it hangs until the timeout in WebClient is reached, and then fails with an Exception.

The following code will not work

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/de/symbol/aapl/dividend-history";
string page = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Using a different URL, the transfer works fine. For example

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "https://www.ariva.de/apple-aktie";
string page = client.DownloadString(url);
```

completes very quick and has the whole html in the page variable.

Using a HttpClient or WebRequest/WebResponse gives the same result on the first URL: block until timeout exception.

Both URLs load fine in a browser, in roughly 2-5 seconds.
Any idea what the problem is, and what solution is available?

I noticed that when using a WebBrowser control on a Windows Forms dialog, the first URL loads with 20+ javascript errors that need to be confirm-clicked. Same can be observed when developer tools are open in a browser when accessing the first URL.

However, WebClient does NOT act on the return it gets. It does not run the javascript, and does not load referenced pictures, css or other scripts, so this should not be a problem.

Thanks!

Ralf

Comment: Best way is to use sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working with non working.  Usually the issue is a missing header in the c# code.  Here are somethings to check 1) Status Code like 200 Done 2) http version 1.0 (stream) 2.2 Chunk.  Chunk mode requires Next Chunk message otherwise times out 3) IE compatibility.  c# code may default to wrong browser setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first site, `"https://www.nasdaq.com/de/symbol/aapl/dividend-history";`, requires:

- [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol) `= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`
- [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback)
- A set [User-Agent Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection)
- A [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer) is, apparently, not required. It should be set anyway.

The `User-agent` here is important. If a recent `User-agent` is specified in the [WebRequest.UserAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent), the WebSite may activate the `Http 2.0` protocol and `HSTS` ([HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)). These are supported/understood only by recent Browsers (as a reference, FireFox 56 or newer).

Using a less recent Browser as `User-agent` is necessary, otherwise the WebSite will expect (and wait for) a *dynamic* response. Using an *older* `User-agent`, the WebSite will activate the `Http 1.1` protocol and never HSTS.

The second site, `"https://www.ariva.de/apple-aktie";`, requires:

- `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`
- No Server Certificate validation is required
- No specific User-agent is required

I suggest to setup a WebRequest (or a corresponding HttpClient setup) this way:
(WebClient *could* work, but it'd probably require a derived Custom Control)

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.nasdaq.com/de/symbol/aapl/dividend-history");
    string destinationFile = "[Some Local File]";
    await HTTPDownload(uri, destinationFile);
    button1.Enabled = true;
}


CookieContainer httpCookieJar = new CookieContainer();

//The 32bit IE11 header is the User-agent used here
public async Task HTTPDownload(Uri resourceURI, string filePath)
{
    // Windows 7 may require to explicitly set the Protocol
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    // Only blindly accept the Server certificates if you know and trust the source
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, ch, sec) => { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;

    var httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(resourceURI);

    try
    {
        httpRequest.CookieContainer = httpCookieJar;
        httpRequest.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds;
        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW32; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";
        httpRequest.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");

        using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                try {
                    int buffersize = 132072;
                    using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath, buffersize, FileOptions.Asynchronous)) {
                        int read;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                        while ((read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    };
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { /* Log or throw */}
                catch (PathTooLongException) { /* Log or throw */}
                catch (IOException) { /* Log or throw */}
            }
        };
    }
    catch (WebException) { /* Log and message */} 
    catch (Exception) { /* Log and message */}
}
```

The first WebSite (`nasdaq.com`) returned payload length is `101.562` bytes
The second WebSite (`www.ariva.de`) returned payload length is `56.919` bytes

Comment: Wow. Simply Wow. I did not yet test this, and barely understand it all (lots of reading on the classes used here) but I am very confident that this is reason and solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've tested the code before posting it (it's a *redacted* version of what I use quite often - in relation to the WebRequest/WebResponse classes). if you have questions, ask away. It would also be good to have a HttpClient version of it (more flexible and, well, *modern*). If you're interested, I can add a PasteBin of it.

Comment: This works - kind of. Time outs still happen, especially for 2nd and further contacts to the web site. A first request never times out. The code above has everything nicely in scope and in using blocks, I cannot see why a 2nd call cannot finish after a first call was successful.

Comment: This can happen if you don't have an active Timeout set on the `WebRequest`. Also, the Server may ask for a Cookie to test if the currently logged IP (which is the same as a previous request) is already *registered* (checks the Cookie expiration date). Try with the code update. Declare the `CookieContainer` as a Field in the class that contains the Download method (so the Cookies will be recycled throughout the requests) and add the `Timeout` as shown.

Comment: Asking a followup Question years later... I am so sorry. This is purely a hobby topic with little time available for it, and I used a different data source with your code, but now looked into the NASDAQ page again. The code above works fine, from a technical perspective, but the content given back is different when run in code compared to a browser. I suspect this is due to javascript in the page, which (I think) replaces the "no data"-parts this code gets back with real data, if it is run. The http request does not run javascript in the response - or does it?

Comment: No, of course it doesn't. This is a quite common scenario. HTML pages generated dynamically by JavaScript (or other client-side scripts) need something that can run the scripts and render the resulting page. I.e., a WebBrowser. -- The WebView2 Control (Chrome-based) is quite useful here (the old Internet Explorer-based WebBrowser Control is no longer a viable option in many cases).

Comment: Thanks again for your input and confirmation of my diagnosis. It helps me a lot to understand what is going on. For reference for everybody else reading this: I chose to use Selenium from VS NuGet packages, which in turns runs a "headless" Google Chrome or FireFox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is a problem with downloading that link (incorrect url, unothorized access, ...), however you may use Async Method to solve the socking part:

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
       //here deal with downloaded file
  };
  client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```