# Downloading CSV file using C# always comes with a timeout error message

Tags: c#, .net, csv, http-headers, webclient

I can not explain this, but a link provided by an API provider which contains an updated list of stock exchange stocks in a normal CSV format would not be downloaded using C#'s client downloading libraries that work elsewhere.

URL: https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&render=download

This link will directly generate a CSV file which can be accessed normally if you click on the link using any browser, no parameters no funny business, direct linlk, however, Any code I try locally below will throw timeout error messages:

Attempt 1:

```
string url = "http://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&render=download";
            Browser browser = null;
            string contents = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);

                browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
                {
                    Headless = false
                });
                var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();


                await page.GoToAsync(url);

                contents = await page.GetContentAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($@"Exception Crawling site :{ex}.");
            }
```

Attempt 2:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Timeout = 30000;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var s = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Attempt 3:

```
 string url = "https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&render=download";

            HttpWebRequest request;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {

                FileStream fs;
                Stream s;
                byte[] read;
                int count;

                read = new byte[256];

                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Timeout = 30000;
                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                s = response.GetResponseStream();

                fs = new FileStream("asd.csv", FileMode.Create);
                while ((count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(read, 0, count);
                    count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                }

                fs.Close();
                s.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException)
            {
                //....
            }
```

Attempt 4:

```
 string url = "https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&render=download";
            string webresponse = string.Empty;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Accept = "*/*";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    webresponse = SR.ReadToEnd();
                    response.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    SR.Close();

                }
                finally
                {
                    request.Abort();
                }
```

Attempt 5:

```
  using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                using (Stream stream = webClient.DownloadFile("https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&render=download", "C:\\Temp.csv"))
                {
                   // return...
                }
            }
```

All of the above attempts come back with this error message:

> System.Net.WebException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond..'

I tried to host the file in another website and that seemed to work with no issues.

Edit:
postman works

[image]

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi Maya, what happens when you do a GET the that url using a rest client like Postman? Try downloading postman and trying to do that real quick..

Comment: [WebClient hangs until timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873685/7444103). In Windows 10, you don't need the `ServicePointManager` stuff (to set the protocol, at least).

Comment: @jbooker I tried that now with postman, it works, updated question with screenshot

Comment: What headers are in your postman request? Have you replicated those in your code? Try RestSharp as well

Answer (score 0):

I only checked 2 and 4.

On your attempt 2 add

```
request.Accept = "*/*";
```

On 4 remove because they are wrong

```
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
```

and it will work.

You can also use Flurl and do it 1 line

string text = await " ".GetStringAsync();